# Css from zenbased theme not getting processed

Tags: 6, theming

I have something weird going on. My font-style of my zen-based custom theme is arial, verdana, sans-serif but what's showing is a serif font type.

I checked all the following:

- CSS compression turned off.
- flushed caches
- Activated a different theme and set it as default, then changed some css and it worked so now I know it has to do with the zenbased custom theme.
- Went into the file manager of my host's cpanel directly and made changes to my stylesheets directly to see if changes would make any effect on the site but no success.
- The site is run on hostgator
- checked to see if stylesheets are mentioned in the info file in a
  proper fashion

Comment: I will answer this question as soon as I can. Here is the answer: "There was a silly couple of charachters at the beginning of my stylesheet and a space between the / and the * that were supposed to start the comment but didn't get processed as comments becuase of the comment.

I was not seeing the comments where grey the whole time."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good checklist for resolving css bugs - I would suggest two more that I've used when stuck on css bugs that may help you resolve this quicker next time.

- Check the element in firebug or developer tools to confirm whether the CSS file you think should be loaded actually is and what css styles are actually being applied to it. In this case, you could have determined that the file was loaded but the styles weren't so you could isolate your debugging to the syntax of the statement.
- Try using an external validator on your css file, like:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Most of the feedback from this will be noise but it may highlight syntax errors in your file.